# Convert a Column oriented file to CSV output using shell

Tags: python, shell, csv

I have a file that  come from map reduce output for the format below that needs conversion to CSV using shell script

```
25-MAY-15
04:20
Client
0000000010
127.0.0.1
PAY
ISO20022
PAIN000
100
1
CUST
API
ABF07
ABC03_LIFE.xml
AFF07/LIFE
100000
Standard Life 

================================================
==================================================

AFF07-B000001

 2000

ABC Corp
..

BE900000075000027


AFF07-B000002

 2000

XYZ corp
..

BE900000075000027



AFF07-B000003

 2000

3MM corp
..

BE900000075000027
```

I need the output like CSV format below where I want to repeat some of the values in the file and add the TRANSACTION ID as below format

```
25-MAY-15,04:20,Client,0000000010,127.0.0.1,PAY,ISO2002,PAIN000,100,1,CUST,API,ABF07,ABC03_LIFE.xml,AFF07/LIFE,100000,Standard Life, 25-MAY-15,04:20,Client,0000000010,127.0.0.1,PAY,ISO2002,PAIN000,100,1,CUST,API,AFF07-B000001, 2000,ABC Corp,..,BE900000075000027

25-MAY-15,04:20,Client,0000000010,127.0.0.1,PAY,ISO2002,PAIN000,100,1,CUST,API,ABF07,ABC03_LIFE.xml,AFF07/LIFE,100000,Standard Life, 25-MAY-15,04:20,Client,0000000010,127.0.0.1,PAY,ISO2002,PAIN000,100,1,CUST,API,AFF07-B000002,2000,XYZ Corp,..,BE900000075000027
```

TRANSACTION  ID is AFF07-B000001,AFF07-B000002,AFF07-B000003 which have different values and I have put a marked line from where the Transaction ID starts . Before the demarkation , the values should be  repeating and the transaction ID column needs to be added along with the repeating values before the line as given in above format

BASH shell script I may need and CentOS is the flavour of linux

I am getting error as below when I execute the code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "abc.py", line 37, in <module>
    main()
  File "abc.py", line 36, in main
    createTxns(fh)
  File "abc.py", line 7, in createTxns
    first17.append( fh.readLine().rstrip() )
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'readLine'
```

Can someone help me out

Comment: You say "using a shell script", but you have a `python` tag. Is solving the problem with a python script acceptable?

Comment: Ya absolutely , I have not tried python yet  . I would like to know how I can implement inside linux as well .

Comment: You need to show what you've tried so far, SO is here to help you with your code not to produce code for you, and give a few more specifics - such as which shell (bash, sh, ksh, csh) you are using, which flavor of Linux, and even which Python as both 2.7 and 3 are available on most Linux systems.

Comment: BASH shell script I may need and CentOS is the flavour of linux

I tried to get the logic in shell , but mostly I am getting searches with AWK and SED , I am not sure how I would implement AWK or SED for the same in shell script or python. I am not sure about which version of Python on my CENTOS system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a correct description of the input file and output format?

The input file consists of:

- 17 lines, followed by
- groups of 10 lines each - each group holding one transaction id

Each output row consists of:

- 29 common fields, followed by
- 5 fields derived from each of the 10-line groups above

So we just translate this into some Python:

```
def createTxns(fh):
  """fh is the file handle of the input file"""

  # 1. Read 17 lines from fh
  first17 = []
  for i in range(17):
    first17.append( fh.readLine().rstrip() )


  # 2. Form the common fields.

  commonFields = first17 + first17[0:12]

  # 3. Process the rest of the file in groups of ten lines.

  while True:
      # read 10 lines
      group = []
      for i in range(10):
        x = fh.readline()
        if x == '':
          break
        group.append( x.rstrip() )

      if len(group) <> 10:
        break                   # we've reached the end of the file

      fields = commonFields + [ group[2], group[4], group[6], group[7[, group[9] ]

      row = ",".join(fields)

      print row

def main():
  with open("input-file", "r") as fh:
    createTxns(fh)

main()
```

This code shows how to:

- open a file handle
- read lines from a file handle
- strip off the ending newline
- check for end of input when reading from a file
- concatenate lists together
- join strings together

Comment: Yes ,thats exactly the correct format for input and output file

Comment: Removed the the equal sign from the post and edited ur answer acccordingly, it was mentioned only for seperation of transaction ID and common input

Comment: Tks for your code and time , I have query ,If we have a 100k transaction that indicates transaction ID  , can we include and modify the code to get the desired CSV output or can we take the repeating transaction ID values(5 Values) in array and display the same way

Comment: I'm not following. What's special about 100K transactions? The code should work on input files of any size.

Comment: Let me give an example, I have Transaction ID AFF07-B000001,AFF07-B000002 ...... till AFF07-B100000 - A 100k Transaction file.  The dynamic values till 100k would be the five fields (AFF07-B000002,2000,XYZ Corp,..,BE900000075000027) , which I want to add it to the common fields 100k times in the same file . I gave it for only for two transactions here for space sake , Will it work for all the Transaction ID if we have more than 3 transaction ID (till 100k)

Comment: It will work. The `while` loop reads the next 10 lines and emits a CSV row. After the first 17 lines of the input file, every subsequent 10 lines creates one CSV row. The first 29 fields of every CSV row will be the same. The last 5 fields of a CSV row are determined by the 10 line group. That's the way it should work, right?

Comment: The `while` loop repeats indefinitely until it can't read anymore 10-line groups. So it will work on any size file.

Comment: Thats lovely , let me try it out and one final query, can we take a mix of dynamic and common fields out of the file and produce another set of CSV file. For example , I want 3 values AFF07-B000002,2000,XYZ Corp from the dynamic list and 3 values from common field and put it another file . Is it possible in same code as well?

Comment: I am fairly new to python, Can you also tell me how to run this script in Linux/Centos

Comment: At the shell: `python script` where `srcipt` is the name of the file containing the program. See also: http://www.python-course.eu/execute_script.php

Comment: tks for that ,Does the output file get stored in the same path where we execute the script

Comment: The output is sent to standard output.

Comment: gr8,do  u have any suggestions for taking some dynamic columns and common columns and send it to a output file

Comment: Just use shell redirection: `python script > output-file`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read [Input and Output](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) if you are going for the python route.

You just have to break the problem down and try it. For the first 17 line use f.readline() and concat into the string. Then the replace method to get the begining of the string that you want in the csv.

```
str.replace("\n", ",")
```

Then use the split method and break them down into the list.

```
str.split("\n")
```

Then write the file out in the loop. Use a counter to make your life easier. First write out the header string

```
25-MAY-15,04:20,Client,0000000010,127.0.0.1,PAY,ISO2002,PAIN000,100,1,CUST,API,ABF07,ABC03_LIFE.xml,AFF07/LIFE,100000,Standard Life, 25-MAY-15,04:20,Client,0000000010,127.0.0.1,PAY,ISO2002,PAIN000,100,1,CUST,API
```

Then write the item in the list with a ",".

```
,AFF07-B000001, 2000,ABC Corp,..,BE900000075000027
```

At the count of 5 write the "\n" with the header again and don't forget to reset your counter so it can begin again.

```
\n25-MAY-15,04:20,Client,0000000010,127.0.0.1,PAY,ISO2002,PAIN000,100,1,CUST,API,ABF07,ABC03_LIFE.xml,AFF07/LIFE,100000,Standard Life, 25-MAY-15,04:20,Client,0000000010,127.0.0.1,PAY,ISO2002,PAIN000,100,1,CUST,API
```

Give it a try and let us know if you need more assistant. I assumed that you have some scripting background :) Good luck!!

Comment: sure, let me try , I am fairly new to python. But let me try with ur logic. Tks for ur help

Comment: that was very illustrative and understandable , tks a lot

Comment: No problem. Python is very powerful. You will love it. I was once in your shoe having to do something similar for a job. Python docs helped a lot. Work with string, learn list then upgrade it to dictinary xD. Good Luck!